# PowerBI encountered error and it needs to close [Ubuntu 18.04]

Tags: 18.04

Following is the error I am getting when I am opening [Power BI](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_BI) in Ubuntu.

```
Unhandled exception: page fault on read access to 0x140000000 in
64-bit code (0x0000000140000000). Register dump:  rip:0000000140000000
rsp:000000000053fdd8 rbp:000000000053ffd0 eflags:00010246 (  R- --  I 
Z- -P- )  rax:0000000140000000 rbx:0000000000000000
rcx:00007fffffeaf000 rdx:0000000000000000  rsi:0000000000000000
rdi:000000000053fe40  r8:000000000053fd00  r9:0000000000000008
r10:0000000000000008  r11:0000000000000246 r12:0000000000000000
r13:0000000000000000 r14:0000000000000000 r15:0000000000000000 Stack
dump: 0x000000000053fdd8:  000000007b47a41a 0000000000000000
0x000000000053fde8:  0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x000000000053fdf8:  0000000000000000 0000000140000000
0x000000000053fe08:  00007fffffeaf000 0000000000000000
0x000000000053fe18:  0000000000000000 ffffffffffffffff
0x000000000053fe28:  000000007b4a6560 000000007b44c600
0x000000000053fe38:  0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x000000000053fe48:  bd7e3c889d7fe537 0000000000000000
0x000000000053fe58:  0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x000000000053fe68:  0000000000000000 bd7e3c88991fe537
0x000000000053fe78:  bd7ecaa024f7e537 0000000000000000
0x000000000053fe88:  0000000000000000 0000000000000000 Backtrace:
=>0 0x0000000140000000 in pbidesktop (+0x0) (0x000000000053ffd0)   1 0x000000007b47a41a in kernel32 (+0x5a419) (0x000000000053ffd0)
0x0000000140000000: popq    %r10 Modules: Module    Address                 Debug
info    Name (16 modules) ELF           7b400000-        7b80e000   Dwarf    
kernel32<elf>   \-PE            7b420000-        7b80e000   \              
kernel32 ELF            7bc00000-        7bd17000   Deferred       
ntdll<elf>   \-PE           7bc20000-        7bd17000   \              
ntdll ELF           7c000000-        7c004000   Deferred       
<wine-loader> ELF           f7d3d000-        f7f67000   Deferred       
ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 PE        140000000-       140042000   Export      
pbidesktop ELF      7f2f7d718000-    7f2f7d92a000   Deferred       
libnss_files.so.2 ELF       7f2f7d92a000-    7f2f7db44000   Deferred      
libnsl.so.1 ELF     7f2f7db44000-    7f2f7dd50000   Deferred       
libnss_nis.so.2 ELF     7f2f7dd50000-    7f2f7df5a000   Deferred       
libnss_compat.so.2 ELF      7f2f7eb29000-    7f2f7ed41000   Deferred     
libgcc_s.so.1 ELF       7f2f7ed41000-    7f2f7f0df000   Deferred       
libm.so.6 ELF       7f2f7f0e1000-    7f2f7f2e5000   Deferred       
libdl.so.2 ELF      7f2f7f2e5000-    7f2f7f6d6000   Deferred       
libc.so.6 ELF       7f2f7f6d6000-    7f2f7f8f5000   Deferred       
libpthread.so.0 Threads: process  tid      prio (all id:s are in hex)
0000000e services.exe   00000034    0   0000002f    0   00000029    0
    00000021    0   00000015    0   00000010    0   0000000f    0 00000011
mscorsvw.exe    0000001a    0   00000019    0   00000018    0   00000012   
0 0000001d winedbg.exe  0000001e    0 0000001f winedevice.exe
    00000028    0   00000023    0   00000022    0   00000020    0 00000026
plugplay.exe    0000002b    0   0000002a    0   00000027    0 0000002d
winedevice.exe  00000037    0   00000033    0   00000031    0   0000002e 
0 0000007e explorer.exe     00000082    0   00000081    0   00000080    0
    0000007f    0 00000083 (D) C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Power BI
Desktop\bin\PBIDesktop.exe  00000084    0 <== System information:
    Wine build: wine-3.0.1 (Ubuntu 3.0.1-0ubuntu1~18.04~ricotz0)
    Platform: x86_64
    Version: Windows 7
    Host system: Linux
    Host version: 4.15.0-22-generic
```

Any idea what could be the issue?

Evidently, I used wine to install it on Ubuntu.

Comment: What is PowerBI?  Is this some proprietary product from someone?

Comment: Yes. Ubuntu's. :P I have edited the question and put the real error over there.

Comment: Um, PowerBI is a Microsoft product. If it doesn't run under Wine then that sounds like it probably won't work. There is no WineHQ test results either. And there is no Linux native variant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you fail to indicate is that PowerBI is a Microsoft proprietary product.

You may be able to install it via Wine, but **Wine is not Windows**.  Nobody else has attempted to install PowerBI with Wine, and there are no test results

**Not every Windows program** can run under Wine.

I attempted to run various PowerBI components in Wine Stable and Devel latest on 16.04 without success (and those Wine versions are newer than what is in the repositories for any Ubuntu release).  I have to conclude by that that PowerBI does not run properly on Wine.

PowerBI does not have any Linux builds either.  Which means short of a virtual Windows environment on VirtualBox, you are unlikely to be able to run PowerBI on Ubuntu natively or via Wine.